# Link Dynamic drop down list to another page using JavaScript or css

Tags: javascript

I am designing a small  website  for my branch.
 Where User should select his year and section and it show his class details.
In my branch 2nd year has 4sections
And 3 rd year has 3 sections
So if I select 3rd year it should display 3 sections dynamically in drop down list and it should  automatically display or go to his class details page when he selects his section
So please help me to get out of this situation
THTHE CODE I TRIED IS

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function populate(s1, s2) {
    var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
    var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
    s2.innerHTML = "";
    if (s1.value == "16") {
      var optionarray = ["|", "5A|A", "5B|B", "5C|C"];

    } else if (s1.value == "17") {
      var optionarray = ["|", "3A|A", "3B|B", "3C|C", "4D|D"];

    }
    for (var option in optionarray) {
      var pair = optionarray[option].split("|")
      var newoption = document.createElement("option");
      newoption.value = pair[0];
      newoption.innerHTML = pair[1];
      s2.options.add(newoption);
    }

  }
</script>
<div class="next">
  <h2>selct your pin and section</h2>
  <select id="slct1" name="slct1" class="drop" onchange="populate('slct1','slct2')">
    <OPTION> </OPTION>
    <option value="16">16124</option>
    <option value="17">17124</option>
  </select>

  <select id="slct2" name="slct2" class="drop"> </select>

</div>
```

Comment: Please share some code you've tried

Comment: i added the code in my body

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard-coding the sections, in the conditional statements better have a mapping like `sectionmapping`. Its easy to maintain and access. I just normally added a `div` to show class details. You can use it to redirect to a new page too.

```js
var sectionmapping = {16:["|","5A|A","5B|B","5C|C"],17:["|","3A|A","3B|B","3C|C","4D|D"]};
function populate(s1,s2)
{
    var s1=document.getElementById(s1);
    var s2=document.getElementById(s2);
    s2.innerHTML="";
    var optionarray = sectionmapping[s1.value];
    for(var option in optionarray)
    {
        var pair=optionarray[option].split("|")
        var newoption=document.createElement("option");
        newoption.value=pair[0];
        newoption.innerHTML=pair[1];
        s2.options.add(newoption);
    }
}

function goToSection(elem)
{
    var details = document.getElementById("classdetails");
    details.style.display="block";
    details.innerHTML = elem.value+"Details";
}
```

```css
.classdetails
{
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
    background : yellow;
    font-family : Lato;
}
```

```html
<div class="next">
    <h2>selct your pin and section</h2>
    <select id="slct1" name="slct1" class="drop" onchange="populate('slct1','slct2')">
    <option value="16">16124</option>
    <option value="17">17124</option>
</select>

<select id="slct2" name="slct2" class="drop" onchange="goToSection(this)">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="5A">A</option>
    <option value="5B">B</option>
    <option value="5C">C</option>
</select>
    
</div>

<div id="classdetails" class="classdetails" style="display:none">

</div>
```

Comment: super bro its worked but i didn't get your point in the last. how can i link to another page using div

Comment: No you can show the details in the `div` if you want or else on selecting a section you can open a new page to show the details.

Comment: just send the perfect code which will be go to another page when user selects his section

Comment: Sorry. Just try it

Comment: What condition should I put in if condition